# Question about the derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Is it true in general that
$$\frac{d}{d(-x)} = -\frac{d}{d(x)}$$

Similarly for partial derivatives
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{(-x)}}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial{(x)}}$$

I saw this in a solution to a problem. Maybe I did not understand correctly and there is something else going on here.

Comment: $$
\frac{d}{{d( - x)}} = \frac{{dx}}{{d( - x)}}\frac{d}{{dx}} = \frac{1}{{\frac{{d( - x)}}{{dx}}}}\frac{d}{{dx}} = \frac{1}{{ - 1}}\frac{d}{{dx}} =  - \frac{d}{{dx}}.
$$

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Here is another (probably more familiar) way to state Gary’s proof above. Define $u(x)=-x$ and apply the chain rule.

Comment: You could also think of $ \ \frac{d}{d(-x)} \ $ as taking the derivative in the "direction" of _decreasing_ $ \ x \ $ , which will change the sign of the derivative in the "increasing" $ \ x-$ direction.